# Automatically reduce the size of a background-image set via CSS when there is not enough width

Tags: css, background-image

The header on my website contains an image set as the background, with the HTML output as below -

```
<div id="header-container">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1>
            <a title="Go home..." href="http://home_url">Blog title</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

The method works just fine, but I'm having issues with mobile devices as my header image is 432px wide.

Because of this I need to amend the code below so that the image reduces in size should the available width of `#header-container .inner` be less than the width ofthe background image.

I've tried several things, including using `background-size: cover;` and `max-width`, but I cannot seem to find a working combination.

How can I overcome this issue?

Here is [a JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apb57trc/) showing the issue.  Just reduce the size of the rendered view to see that the image does not shrink.

And here is the CSS that I am using -

```
#header-container .inner h1{
    background:                 transparent url(res/title-white.png) no-repeat center left;
    -moz-background-size:       432px auto;
    -webkit-background-size:    432px auto;
    background-size:            432px auto;
    height:                     85px;
    margin:                     0;
    width:                      432px;
}
#header-container .inner h1 a{
    display:        block;
    height:         85px;
    text-indent:    -9999px;
    width:          432px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `background-size: contain`, not `background-size: cover`, in combination with `min/max-width`.

Change your CSS like this.

```
#header-container .inner h1{
    background: transparent url(http://apps.gwtrains.co.uk/apklibrary/wp-content/themes/apklibrary/images/logo-white.png) no-repeat center left;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 85px;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 432px;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
#header-container{
  background-color: #053525;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #4DC386;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header-container .inner{
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1000px;
 position: relative;
}

#header-container .inner h1{
 background: transparent url(http://apps.gwtrains.co.uk/apklibrary/wp-content/themes/apklibrary/images/logo-white.png) no-repeat center left;
 background-size: contain;
  max-height: 85px;
 margin: 0;
 max-width: 432px;
  position: relative;
}
#header-container .inner h1:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-container">
 <div class="inner">
  <h1>
  </h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that reduces the image size correctly, however I'm still left with the height of 85px.  What I'd like to do is reduce that to the height of the image when contained with a maximum of 85px.  Obviously I can't just set `max-height`, and I don't know of any way of determining the height of the rendered `background-image` on the fly.

Comment: For that you can use the "padding" trick to keep image ratio: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/

Comment: Cheers for the link, I'm just having a look.  I am now thinking though that `min-height` may be the way to go though, to avoid the header looking silly of it gets too small.

Comment: @DavidGard I updated my answer to show you the concept.

Comment: @DavidGard The percentage in `padding: 20%` should be your image width/height ratio, like 500px / 100 px = 20%.

Answer (score 0):

@media query might help here:

```
#header-container .inner h1{
    background:                 transparent url(res/title-white.png) no-repeat center left;
    background-size:            432px auto;
    height:                     85px;
    margin:                     0;
    width:                      432px;
}

@media (max-width: 432px){
    #header-container .inner h1{
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Comment: I though of this, but with some may different devices with different resolutions, it's impossible to correctly judge.  Plus doing it this way means that the height/width remains the same, so even if the image resizes, the `h1` container would still overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can force this by avoiding the background image altogether as you replace it with a regular image in the `<img>` tag. Layer containers of content (one with the image and another with text) on top of each other with absolute position and z-index. It's a workaround to the background image problems I've experienced similar to yours and the layers provide nice flexibility for managing content.

```css
#z1 {
  z-index: 1;
}
#z2 {
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 5%;
  color: white;
}

#z1, #z2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="z1">
    <img width="100%" src="http://www.verolago.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/sailboat.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="z2">
    <p>I'm on a boat!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries for mobile devices. Like:

```
 @media all and (max-width: 540px){
  #header-container .inner h1{
    -moz-background-size:       260px auto;
    -webkit-background-size:    260px auto;
    background-size:            260px auto;
    width: 280px;
  }
  #header-container .inner h1 a{
    width:          260px;
  }
}
```